# Default Branch on Payments and Applications (AR302000)

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I want to display the 'Default Branch' (screenshot 1) from the Customers' (AR303000) Shipping tab to the Payment and Applications'(AR302000) 'LOAD DOCUMENTS' dialog box's, 'Company Branch'(screenshot 2)

**Screenshot 1: Customers Default Branch**

[image]

**Screenshot 2: Load Document Company Branch (Payments and Applications)**

[image]

The code I have does not seem to be displaying the Default Branch from the Customers Shipping tab to the Payments and Applications Company Branch.

**Code snippet:**

```
 public class ARPaymentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.AR.ARPaymentEntry>
    {
        #region Event Handlers


        protected void LoadOptions_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {

            var row = (LoadOptions)e.Row;

            if (row == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            ARPayment aRPayment = Base.Document.Current;

            if (aRPayment == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Customer customer = PXSelect<Customer,
                                   Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Required<ARPayment.customerID>>>>
                                   .Select(Base, aRPayment.CustomerID);


            if (customer == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Location location = PXSelect<Location,
                                   Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Required<ARPayment.customerID>>,
                                     And<Location.locationID, Equal<Required<Customer.defLocationID>>>>>
                                       .Select(Base, aRPayment.CustomerID, customer.DefLocationID);

            if (location == null)
            {
                return;
            }

             row.BranchID = location.CBranchID;



        }

       
        [PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Replace)]
        //  [OrganizationTree(typeof(organizationID), typeof(branchID), onlyActive: true)]
        
        protected virtual void LoadOptions_OrgBAccountID_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would move your code into FieldDefaulting for the LoadOptions, rather than row selected.

```
    protected virtual void LoadOptions_OrgBAccountID_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs args, PXFieldDefaulting del)
    {
        var row = (LoadOptions)e.Row;

        if (row == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ARPayment aRPayment = Base.Document.Current;

        if (aRPayment == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Customer customer = PXSelect<Customer,
                               Where<Customer.bAccountID, Equal<Required<ARPayment.customerID>>>>
                               .Select(Base, aRPayment.CustomerID);


        if (customer == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        Location location = PXSelect<Location,
                               Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Required<ARPayment.customerID>>,
                                 And<Location.locationID, Equal<Required<Customer.defLocationID>>>>>
                                   .Select(Base, aRPayment.CustomerID, customer.DefLocationID);

        if (location == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        //set the default with customers branch
        args.NewValue = location.CBranchID;
    }
```